# Can Heroku use x64 installation of Git on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, heroku

I had previously installed Git x64 on Windows 7 (So it is sitting in `C:\Program Files\Git`). Then I installed Heroku toolbelt.

It included an installation of Git as well, and installed a x32 bit version of Git (as well as a different version). I was not happy about this, since it is polluting my already tight PATH variable, which bombs out on Windows 7 after it exceeds 2048 chars (approx..). So I uninstalled Git x32 version.

Git still works for me on the command line, but if I issue the heroku command:

```
git push heroku master
```

It gives the error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/infinite....git/': 
error setting certificate verify locations:                                                                                                           
CAfile: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt                                             
CApath: none
```

So it is looking for ca-bundle.crt. I see this same file exists under C:\Program Files\Git... (i.e. under the x64 bit installation).

Is it possible to make Heroku use that installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue by simply copying the `ca-bundle.crt` file from the x64 installation to the required folder i.e. `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, even though Git 32 bit is not installed...